# How to get approximate line number of large files

Tags: python, filereader

I have CSV files with up to 10M+ rows.  I am attempting to get the total line numbers of a file so I can split the processing of each file into a multiprocessing approach.  To do this, I will set a start and end line for each sub-process to handle.  This cuts down my processing time from 180s to 110s for a file size of 2GB.  However, in order to do this, It requires to know the line number count.  If I attempt to get the exact line number count, it will take ~30seconds.  I feel like this time is wasted as an approximate with the final thread possibly having to read an extra hundred thousand lines or so, would only add a couple seconds as apposed to the 30 seconds it takes to get the exact line count.

How would I go about getting an approximate line count for files? I would like this estimate to be within 1 million lines (Preferably within a couple hundred thousand lines).  Would something like this be possible?

Comment: Are all the lines approximately the same length?

Comment: @khelwood They should be, as it's all table data.

Comment: Then dividing the total file length by the length of any one line will give you an approximate line count

Comment: Have you attempted to code this? You can start with the pandas library.

Comment: try a mapreduce job, it will take care of dividing data into equal splits on its own.

Comment: @user8212173 pandas was very slow and speed is my #1 priority.

Comment: @AnkushRathi Thanks, I will look into this.

Comment: Why do you need to know the total line count in order to split up the processing. Can’t you just pick an arbitrary chunk size for each batch?

Comment: @JoelCornett what if the end of a chunk is in the middle of a line? I need full row data when processing

Comment: @asd3sfg python has a builtin line-buffered csv reader in the `csv` module. Using this, you can read in one line at a time. I don’t think there is a need for you to know the line count ahead of time.

Comment: @JoelCornett Yes, i've used that before. but how would I split up that job using the `csv.reader`? Lets say I have a 2gb file with 20m rows.  I want to split that up into 4 sub processes (so a different CPU core is processing each chunk of data), each handling 5m rows of data.  How is the `csv` library going to help me with that (Besides the obvious fact of reading a csv line with a deliminator)?

Comment: @asd3sfg well you would pick some arbitrary chunk size (say 1024), and read that many rows into a list. Then you would dispatch that list to a process pool (use `multiprocessing.Pool`). Repeat as many times as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This will be horribly inaccurate but it will get the size of a row and divide it against the size of the file.

```
import sys
import csv
import os

with open("example.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    row1   = next(reader)

    _Size = sys.getsizeof(len("".join(row1)))

print("Size of Line 1 > ",_Size)
print("Size of File   >",str(os.path.getsize("example.csv")))
print("Approx Lines   >",(os.path.getsize("example.csv") / _Size))
```

> (Edit) If you change the last line to
>   `math.floor(os.path.getsize("example.csv") / _Size)` It's actually
>   quite accurate

Comment: Thanks, I think I will use an approach like this but take the average of the first 100 rows, seems like the best approach I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you split the file into chunks of similar size, before even parsing.

The example code below will split `data.csv` into 4 chunks of approximately equal size, by seeking and searching for the next line break. It'll then call `launch_worker()` for each chunk, indicating the start offset and length of the data that worker should handle.

Ideally you'd use a [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) for each worker.

```py
import os

n_workers = 4

# open the log file, and find out how long it is
f = open('data.csv', 'rb')
length_total = f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)

# split the file evenly among n workers
length_worker = int(length_total / n_workers)

prev_worker_end = 0

for i in range(n_workers):
    # seek to the next worker's approximate start
    file_pos = f.seek(prev_worker_end + length_worker, os.SEEK_SET)

    # see if we tried to seek past the end of the file... the last worker probably will
    if file_pos >= length_total:                                            # <-- (3)
        # ... if so, this worker's chunk extends to the end of the file
        this_worker_end = length_total

    else:
        # ... otherwise, look for the next line break
        buf = f.read(256)                                                   # <-- (1)
        next_line_end = buf.index(b'\n')                                    # <-- (2)

        this_worker_end = file_pos + next_line_end

    # calculate how long this worker's chunk is
    this_worker_length = this_worker_end - prev_worker_end
    if this_worker_length > 0:
        # if there is any data in the chunk, then try to launch a worker
        launch_worker(prev_worker_end, this_worker_length)

    # remember where the last worker got to in the file
    prev_worker_end = this_worker_end + 1
```

Some expansion on markers in the code:

1. You'll need to make sure that the `read()` will consume at least an entire line. Alternatively you could loop to perform multiple `read()`s if you don't know how long a line could be upfront.
2. This assumes `\n` line endings... you may need to modify for your data.
3. The last worker will get slightly less data to handle that the others... this is because we always search-forwards for the next line break. The more workers you have, the less data the final worker gets. It's not very significant (~200-500 bytes in my testing).

Make sure you always use binary-mode, as text-mode can give you wonky `seek()`s / `read()`s.

An example `launch_worker()` would look like this:

```py
def launch_worker(offset, length):
    print('Starting a worker... using chunk %d - %d (%d bytes)...' 
           % ( offset, offset + length, length ))

    with open('log.txt', 'rb') as f:
        f.seek(offset, os.SEEK_SET)
        worker_buf = f.read(length)

    lines = worker_buf.split(b'\n')

    print('First Line:')
    print('\t' + str(lines[0]))
    print('Last Line:')
    print('\t' + str(lines[-1]))
```